# Change the time when picking a date?

Tags: org-mode, org-capture, calendar

I am using a `%^T` element in my `org-capture-template`. This prompts me this need calendar buffer, where I can pick a date.

I can move around by using `SHIFT+<arrow>`. It maps to `calendar-forward-day`. How can I change the time in this view?

Is there something similar like `add one hour` or `set minutes to 00`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just type a time, eg 9am, or 1:30pm in the minibuffer.